# How can I incorporate angular momentum in this code?

Tags: python, computational-physics, computational-mechanics

I'm currently working on the 3-body problem, and I was writing a code to plot the trajectories of all 3 bodies while also manipulating the angular momentum of the system. I found a code online and tweaked it a little bit to match what I want. I was successful in plotting their trajectories; however, I couldn't measure their angular momentum.

Angular momentum is defined as the cross product of position $\vec{r}$ and momentum $\vec{p}$ (I have set the masses to be $1$, so momentum is the same as velocity in my case). I have tried to concatenate the arrays which represent the $x$ and $y$ components of the position and velocity of each body and used np.cross to calculate the cross product, but it didn't work. I'm not sure if my reasoning is wrong or I have just written the code wrong. Does anybody have a suggestion on how I could do this?

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Inital Conditions
y0 = [-1        ,#x1
  0             ,#y1
  1             ,#x2
  0             ,#y2
  0             ,#x3
  0             ,#y3
  0.306893      ,#vx1
  0.125507      ,#vy1
  0.306893      ,#vx2
  0.125507      ,#vy2
  -2*0.306893   ,#vx3
  -2*0.125507]   #vy3

# Time steps and the total number of steps
N = 10000
T = 0.001 

#Definition of the Function 
def ThreeBody(t,y):
 f = np.zeros(12)

 # The velocities of the three bodies
 f[0] = y[6]
 f[1] = y[7]
 f[2] = y[8]
 f[3] = y[9]
 f[4] = y[10]
 f[5] = y[11]

 # The x and y positions of each object respectively
 f[6] = -(y[0]-y[2])/(((y[0]-y[2])**2+(y[1]-y[3])**2)**(3/2)) \
       -(y[0]-y[4])/(((y[0]-y[4])**2+(y[1]-y[5])**2)**(3/2))
       
 f[7] = -(y[1]-y[3])/(((y[0]-y[2])**2+(y[1]-y[3])**2)**(3/2)) \
       -(y[1]-y[5])/(((y[0]-y[4])**2+(y[1]-y[5])**2)**(3/2))
                 
 f[8] = -(y[2]-y[0])/(((y[2]-y[0])**2+(y[3]-y[1])**2)**(3/2)) \
       -(y[2]-y[4])/(((y[2]-y[4])**2+(y[3]-y[5])**2)**(3/2))
       
 f[9] = -(y[3]-y[1])/(((y[2]-y[0])**2+(y[3]-y[1])**2)**(3/2)) \
       -(y[3]-y[5])/(((y[2]-y[4])**2+(y[3]-y[5])**2)**(3/2))
                 
 f[10]= -(y[4]-y[0])/(((y[4]-y[0])**2+(y[5]-y[1])**2)**(3/2)) \
       -(y[4]-y[2])/(((y[4]-y[2])**2+(y[5]-y[3])**2)**(3/2))
      
 f[11]= -(y[5]-y[1])/(((y[4]-y[0])**2+(y[5]-y[1])**2)**(3/2)) \
       -(y[5]-y[3])/(((y[4]-y[2])**2+(y[5]-y[3])**2)**(3/2))

 return f


 #Solving for the positions of all bodies
 t = np.linspace(0,N*T,N)
 solution = solve_ivp(ThreeBody,[0,800],y0,t_eval=t,rtol=1e-12)


 #Evolution in Position with respect to Time
 plt.plot(solution.y[0],solution.y[1],'-g') #Positions body 1
 plt.plot(solution.y[2],solution.y[3],'-r') #Positions body 2
 plt.plot(solution.y[4],solution.y[5],'-b') #Positions body 3
 plt.ylabel("Position(y)")
 plt.xlabel("Position(x)")
 plt.show()

 plt.plot(t,solution.y[0])
 plt.ylabel("Position (x)")
 plt.xlabel("Time")
 plt.show()
```

Comment: If the Newton law is implemented correctly in the code then conservation of angular momentum (as well as conservation of linear momentum and energy) will be a consequence of the time-evolution equations.

Comment: I know that. I just want to be able to measure the angular momentum of the bodies. Also, I should be able to set the angular momentum to 0 if I set the angular momentum of the third body, for instance, to be equal to the negative of the sum of the angular momentum of the other two bodies.

Comment: The cross product only works for 3D vectors. You would need to add a (zero) z component, to then get the only relevant entry in the z component of the cross product. You could as well just compute that as `det([[x1,y1],[vx1,vy1]])` or its direct form `x1*vy1-y1*vx1`.

Comment: @LutzLehmann So, I can like take the first entry for each variable and compute the determinant and put the result in an array. Then, I can plot it versus time. Is that correct?

Comment: Ehm, no? You do that for position and impulse of each body and add them together, or plot them separately, the 1 is the index of the body like in your code.

Comment: That is what I meant. Thanks for the help!